# Pandas: conditionally matching rows in a smaller data frame

Tags: python, pandas

(update: added `desired` data frame)

Let me start by saying that I'm *reasonably confident* that I found a solution to this problem several years ago, but I have not been able to re-find that solution.

Questions that address similar problems, but don't solve my particular problem include:

- [Efficiently select rows that match one of several values in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485375/efficiently-select-rows-that-match-one-of-several-values-in-pandas-dataframe)
- [Efficiently adding calculated rows based on index values to a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798857/efficiently-adding-calculated-rows-based-on-index-values-to-a-pandas-dataframe?rq=1)
- [Compare Python Pandas DataFrames for matching rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29464234/compare-python-pandas-dataframes-for-matching-rows)

---

### The Question

Let's say I have a data frame with many columns that I am working on:

```
big = pd.DataFrame({'match_1': [11, 12, 51, 52]})
big
   match_1
0       11
1       12
2       51
3       52
```

I also have smaller data frame that, in theory, maps some conditional statement to a desired value:

```
# A smaller dataframe that we use to map values into the larger dataframe
small = pd.DataFrame({'is_even': [True, False], 'score': [10, 200]})
small
  is_even  score
0    True     10
1   False    200
```

The goal here would be to use a conditional statement to match each row in `big` to a single row in `small`.  Assume that `small` is constructed such that there was always be one, and only one, match for each row in `big`.  (If there has to be multiple rows in `small` that match, just pick the first one.)

The desired output would be something like:

```
desired = pd.DataFrame({'match_1': [11, 12, 51, 52], 'metric': [200, 10, 200, 10]})
desired
 match_1  metric
0       11     200
1       12      10
2       51     200
3       52      10
```

I'm pretty sure that the syntax would look similar to:

```
big['score'] = small.loc[small['is_even'] == ( (big['match_1'] / 2) == 0), 'score']
```

This won't work because `small['is_even']` is a Series of length 2, while `( (big['match_1'] / 2) == 0)` is a Series of length 4.  What I'm looking to do is, **for each row in `big`, find the one row in `small` that matches based on a conditional.**

If I can get a sequence that contains the correct row in `small` that matches each row in `big`, then I could do something like:

```
`big['score'] = small.loc[matching_rows, 'score']
```

The question I have is: **how do I generate the Sequence `matching rows`**?

---

### Things that (I think) aren't quite what I want:

If the columns in `big` and `small` were to match simply on constant values, this would be a straight forward use of either `big.merge()` or `big.groupby()`, however, in my case, the mapping can be an arbitrarily complex boolean conditional, for example:

```
(big['val1'] > small['threshold']) & (big['val2'] == small['val2']) & (big['val3'] > small['min_val']) & (big['val3'] < small['max_val'])
```

Solutions that rely on `isin()`, `any()`, etc, don't work, because the conditional check can be arbitrarily complex.

I could certainly create a function to `apply()` to the bigger DataFrame, but again, I'm pretty sure there was a simpler solution.

---

The answer may come down to 'calculate some intermediate columns until you can do a simple merge' or 'just use `apply()`, but I could swear that there was a way to do what I've described above.

Comment: Does dataframes derive in a database? If so, your conditionally matching (one-to-many) can be handled in SQL. No need for pandas to restructure in memory.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use a `merge` in which the `on_left` is not a column, but a vector of keys. It's made simpler by setting the index of `small` to be `is_even`:

```
>>> small.set_index('is_even', inplace=True)
>>> condition = big['match_1'] % 2 == 0
>>> pd.merge(big, small, left_on=condition, right_index=True, how='left')
   match_1  score
0       11    200
1       12     10
2       51    200
3       52     10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can index `small` with True and False and just do a straight `.ix` lookup on it. Not sure it's all that much tidier than the intermediate column/merge:

```
In [127]: big = pd.DataFrame({'match_1': [11, 12, 51, 52]})

In [128]: small = pd.DataFrame({'score': [10, 200]}, index=[True, False])

In [129]: big['score'] = small.ix[pd.Index(list(big.match_1 % 2 == 0))].score.values

In [130]: big
Out[130]:
   match_1  score
0       11    200
1       12     10
2       51    200
3       52     10
```